# Odoo default data for binary field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I'm developing a custom module in Odoo 13 CE. I've declared a model that contains a binary image field like this:

```py
class allergenCategories(models.Model):
    _name = "mrp_nutrition.allergen.categories"
    _description = "Categorías de alérgenos"
    name = fields.Char("Nombre", required=True)
    image = fields.Binary("Icono de alérgeno")
```

So it's a simple class that only contains a name field and an image field. I know how to preload default values in other models to skip the manually creation of most common values by using a data.xml file, but this file can (as far as I know) only store text values for the records.

I guess there's a way to call a .png file to be loaded from the module folders directly but I don't know how to achieve it and I can't find any further information from Odoo's documentation nor Stack Overflow's questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Data Files](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/data.html#field) documentation:

> **type**
> if a `type` attribute is provided, it is used to interpret and convert the field’s content.
> The field’s content can be provided through an external file using the `file` attribute, or through the node’s body.

You can set the `type` and `file` to load like following:

```
<field name="image" type="base64" file="base/static/img/country_flags/ad.png"/>
```

The above example is taken from the [base/data/res_country_data.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/data/res_country_data.xml) file

Comment: Great! It works perfectly. I probably skip that part of the documentation, cause I really read it and didn't notice it.